# How to use indices on a join in MySQL using inequality comparison

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to merge two tables on the condition that the value for a row in the first is greater than a row in the second table. Or in code:

```
select * from Computers  join Locations
    ON Computers.ip_number > Locations.ipLower;
```

All of the columns referenced (ip_number and ipLower) are indices in their respective tables with very high cardinality. However, calling explain on the statement states that no indices are used in the call. How can I force MySQL to use indices on the join statement?

Additional info:
I am using MySQL version 5.6.17.  The query correctly uses indices if the join condition is equality instead of greater than. The indices are binary tree type.

Edit: The ip_number variable referenced is an integer which is derived from an IP address, not the IP address itself.

Comment: what happens to the explain if you move that to the where clause?

Comment: @Alan Asher, what exactly do you want to move to the where clause, and what are you considering the where clause?

Comment: the `Computers.ip_number > Locations.ipLower`

Comment: And, again, what are you calling the where clause in the code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL uses indexes when its query planner judges that there is performance to be gained by doing so.

It is not surprising that it doesn't make that judgement in this case; each row of your first table is, by your `ON` condition, joined to a great many rows of your second table.

Don't worry about what indexes get used by the query planner until you have a query that makes sense in your application. It's not clear the one you've shown makes sense. Its result set will be quite large.

This query might make more sense.  It might also use range scans on the index on `Computers.ip_number`.

```
select * 
  from Computers  
  join Locations ON Computers.ip_number BETWEEN Locations.ipLower AND Locations.ipLupper
```

But, you probably should enumerate the columns you want in the result set and avoid `SELECT *` if you want decent performance.

Also, don't forget that IP addresses in dotted quad form `192.168.167.66` don't collate reasonably. That is, using inequalities like `<` or `BETWEEN` to compare them with each other doesn't really work.

Comment: Apologies, I simplified my actual query in order to highlight the problem. I am in fact using a query of the form you describe (using a between statement), and it is still the case that no indices are used. The locations table is well over a million rows long and scanning through the entire range is quite slow. Is there a method to ignore the query planner's logic and force it to use the indices?